# Angular2: Wait http request to valorize a variable

Tags: angular, http, cookies, token

I need in my getResource method to request at resource server the refresh of my tokens(wrapped inside cookies) .

After that, i'll valorize cookie variable to build the right header to the resource server

```
  getResource(resourceUrl) {


var cookie;
var resultString;

if (!Cookie.get("access_token")) { //refresh workflow
  let params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('grant_type','refresh_token');
  params.append('refresh_token',Cookie.get("refresh_token"));
  params.append('client_id','web_app');

  let headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8','Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa("web_app:")});
  let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

  this._http.post('http://localhost:9997/oauth/token',params.toString(),options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .toPromise()
    .then(data =>{
      Cookie.set("access_token", data.access_token, 0.00034722222);
      Cookie.set("refresh_token", data.refresh_token, 1);
    });
}
  cookie = Cookie.get("access_token");//this must be valorize after expire with refresh

var headers = new Headers({
  'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + cookie});                          

var options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

return this._http.get(resourceUrl, options)
  .map(res => res.text())
  .toPromise();}
```

I'm trying to use async/await pattern but i don't reach the goal. Any idea?

Comment: Why are you using promises instead of observables?

Comment: async/await pattern wraps the request inside a promise. The problem persist with observables.